# Unable to load a URL in iFrame

Tags: x-frame-options

I am trying to load a URL into an iFrame, but I am getting the following message:

"Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/register does not permit framing."

In the httprequester the X-Frame-Options are set to "DENY".

I am using nginx and when I checked all the nginx config files, they are having the x-frame-options all set to "ALLOW-FROM ..."

Any idea where can I find the correct config files which have the x-frame-options set to "DENY"

Thanks,
P M